# Rendering problems - The following classes could not be found

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-xml

I added [this library](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal) to support Circular Reveal on pre-Lollipop devices.
I've read the setup guide and everything actually works great! It compiles without errors, and works in the application just as expected. However, I'm facing some "Rendering problems" warning that I can't get rid of. It says:

```
Rendering Problems 
The following classes could not be found:
- io.codetail.widget.RevealLinearLayout (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.
```

My .xml file:

```xml
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SingleGameActivity"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:background="@color/game_background">

    <!-- Some other stuff -->

    <io.codetail.widget.RevealLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newPlaceWrapper"
            android:background="#95000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textNewPlace"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </io.codetail.widget.RevealLinearLayout>
<!-- Some other stuff -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

My build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "//"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: It say `compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0@aar'` in the readme. Did you try to include the `aar` file?

Comment: @KNeerajLal I had an issue that is described here: https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal/issues/32 Some guy said to remove `@aar`, and it indeed worked. EDIT: just tried to add `@aaf` to see if that resolves the issue, but nope.